# Testing grails plugin: doWithSpring and doWithDynamicMethods

Tags: unit-testing, testing, grails, integration-testing

I'm working on open source plugin for grails named [grails routing](https://github.com/padcom/grails-routing)

I have hit the bug which simply defines like that: `doWithSpring` (which is called before `doWithDynamicMethods`) initialize and starts up the bean, which immediately run some custom code. This custom code could use dynamic methods which are **not yet injected** (coz `doWithDynamicMethods` is not yet called). I know how to fix it, however I'd like to create an integration test which proves my logic is right and hit the bug. Then I'll commit code changes which will pass this integration test. The only thing I need is a way to run some custom initialization of `grailsApplication.routeClasses` **BEFORE** `doWithSpring` is called. However, as I see integration tests are started **after** spring initialization is done. Is there some way to trick it from integration test? E.g. an annotation similar to `@Before` and `@BeforeClass` which runs **BEFORE** grails spring initilazation take place?

**UPDATE 1**
I tried to use `conf/spring/resources.groovy` which for plugins are used only on testing phase. However, I found that it's called **after** `doWithSpring` method.

Call order is as the following:

```
doWithSpring
resources.groovy
doWithDynamicMethods
| Running 1 integration test...
@BeforeClass
| Running 1 integration test... 1 of 1
```